# Changing an ApiGateway restapi stage deployment via the cli or sdk

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli, aws-serverless

I have a system in place for creating new deployments but I would like to be able to change a stage to use a previous deployment.  You can do this via the aws console but it appears it's not an option for v1 API gateways via the SDK or CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done via CLI for V1 APIs. You will have to run two commands -> `get-deployments` and `update-stage`. Get the deployment ID from output of first and use it in the second.

```
$ aws apigateway get-deployments --rest-api-id $API_ID

$ aws apigateway update-stage --rest-api-id $API_ID --stage $STAGE_NAME --patch-operations op=replace,path=/deploymentId,value=$DEPLOYMENT_ID
```

[get-deployments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-deployments.html)
[update-stage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-stage.html)